# AngularJSTodo not working

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

after a fresh install of the new VS 2015 Preview on windows 8.1 (german) with Visual-studio-cordova added i tried to run the AngularJSTodo sample project for the andriod platform within the ripple emulator. I don't get any error while compiling and running the app in the ripple emulator. Only 2 javascript wanrings (see link below).
But the app isn't behaving as expected. The only thing i seen in the emulator device window is the headline "What needs to be done?". That's all. Did i missed something from the tutorial?

thx in advance.

madas

[VS warnings](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/vs201501wk8fvnu6ah.jpg)
[Chrome output](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/vs201502oy52jerzvc.jpg)

Comment: It looks like it's behaving as expected. [Here's a web version](http://todomvc.com/examples/angularjs/#/) of the same app for comparison. Is something broken in the app itself?

Comment: Type something and click Enter, if it adds the item then it is working.